# Installing Ubuntu 14.04 updates breaks fglrx

Tags: 14.04, drivers, updates, fglrx

I am using the older Ubuntu 14.04 because I read this: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/03/ubuntu-drops-amd-catalyst-fglrx-driver-16-04

I play games on my computer, and the open source drivers do not give me good performance. Ubuntu 14.04 has updates available, but installing them causes it to switch to the open source Xorg driver. After the update, if I go to Settings -> Software and Updates -> Additional Drivers, I tried clicking on the fglrx-updates driver and applying changes, but it automatically switches back to Xorg. I tried reinstalling fglrx drivers with apt-get and it could not update because there are conflicts with multiple Xorg packages and it says that there are broken packages. I also tried using aptitude to reinstall them, but that did not help.

Currently, I am using a reinstalled Ubuntu 14.04 and avoiding the updates because I need fglrx to work so I can play games with good performance. Is there some way I could fix this so I could enjoy both Ubuntu updates and good game performance?

In order to get the command line output from the problems, I could create a disk image backup of my main hard drive so I can go through my previous steps to reproduce the problem, and provide command line output. Then, I can roll back to my current system using the disk image.

Comment: Having similar issues.  Can't seem to create the packages manually either using the run script.  Have the crash report here: http://pastebin.com/raw/jnYQJPG0

Comment: I think your issues are caused by the hardware enablement stack, backported to 14.04 from 16.04. You could just not install them?
"sudo apt-get update" and "sudo apt-get upgrade" would still install the rest of the updates